# Gradient of mappings between manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_identity

What is the definition of a gradient of $f:M\rightarrow N$?

I only know that of a function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as

$<\nabla f,X>=X(f)=X^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, so
$\nabla f=g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\partial_i$. But I have no idea what it is if $f=(f^1,\dots,f^n)$ is $n$-dimensional. At first I guess it might be like a matrix, but if so what is $|\nabla f|$?

Comment: there is a link on the page you are citing on which the concept is defined.

Comment: $\frac 1 2 |\nabla f|^2$ is the *energy density* of $f$, which you can find defined early in [the wikipedia page on harmonic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_map).

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis Are df and $\nabla f$ the same thing?

Comment: In this context, yes.

Comment: @ Anthony Carapetis Could you please explain what is $\nabla(du)$ in [Bochner indentity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_identity)?

Comment: It's the covariant derivative of the section $du \in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes u^* TN),$ taken using the natural connection induced on this bundle by the Riemannian connections of $M,N.$ If you're not familiar with this kind of construction, see e.g. sections 1.5-1.7 of [this book](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf).